# Cannot send event handler to child element through props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to send a form-submission handler to a child element through props. Everything renders, but when I click the submit button, I get no alert (see `alert('Hi')` in the `handleSubmit` function), and I also don't see the elements of `SearchResults` change. Instead, the whole page reloads and I'm back in the initial state. What is wrong?

**Searcher.js**:

```
class Searcher extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            results: [
                {name:'1', key:0}, 
                {name:'2', key:1}
            ]
        };
    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        alert('Hi');
        this.setState({
            results: [
                {name: 'hi', key: 0},
                {name: 'again', key: 1}
            ]
        })
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SearchForm/>
                <SearchResults results={this.state.results} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Searcher;
```

**SearchForm.js**:

```
class SearchForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {value: ''};
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {    this.setState({value: event.target.value});  }

    render() {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      );
    }
  }

  export default SearchForm;
```

**SearchResults.js**:

```
class SearchResults extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            this.props.results.map((result) => (<div key={result.key}>{result.name}</div>))
        )
    }
}

export default SearchResults;
```

Comment: you are not passing `handleSubmit` in your `<SearchForm/>` in **Searcher.js**

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: You should be passing `handleSubmit` from the Searcher to SearchForm...
i.e. `<SearchForm handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `handeSubmit` as props in `<SearchForm />` in Searcher.js

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SearchForm handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/> // Pass Handle Submit 
                <SearchResults results={this.state.results} /> // I don't see handleSubmit being used in SearchResults
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `handleSubmit` to `SearchForm` or its value will be `undefined`

```
class Searcher extends React.Component {
    ...

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        alert('Hi');
        ...
    }

    render() {
        return <SearchForm handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
    }
}

export default Searcher;
```